# Can we delete a reply of our own Google Play App's review

Tags: google-play-services, google-play-console

I have replied to a review of an app in Google Play Store. After replying, Google Play Console only shows me the options to edit the replay, but no option to delete. Is there a way to delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whit I did is
1 change the keyboard language of my phone to Arabic
2 any reply i want to delete i edit it by add a special Arabic character
The reply will still there but it will be empty